# validate white space at the beginning and end of string with regex

Tags: php, laravel, string

someone who can help me with a regular expression to be able to validate the blank spaces at the beginning and end of a string, currently I manage this but it does not work for me.

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();

    $validatedData = $request->validateWithBag('marcas', [
        'marca'       => ['required', 'regex:/^\s+|[a-zA-Z\t\h]+|(^$)+|\s+$/'],
        'descripcion' => ['required'],
    ]);

    $show = Marca::create($validatedData);

    DB::commit();

    $success =  toast('Marca agregada con exito!', 'success', 'top-right');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();

    toast('Datos requeridos o invalidos!','error','top-right');        
}
   
return redirect()->route('marcas.index', with('success'));
```

Example:

valid data:no space

invalid data: space at the beginning

this is so that when my user fills an input and adds a space either at the beginning or end of the text to be saved, the regex detects it

Comment: Please provide sample valid and invalid data. It's not clear from the code as to what you are trying to match.

Comment: valid data:no space
invalid data:  space at the beginning

Comment: You might try this: `/^\S([\s\S]*\S)?$/`.

Comment: Alternatively, could use `trim(...)` on the input to remove any leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: @KevinCarrascal remember to ALWAYS read the documentation as it is already explained in there, because you are no magician, you have no other way of knowing this than reading the docs, it is the only way to learn how Laravel works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Input Trimming & Normalization](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization)

> By default, Laravel includes the `App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings` and
> `App\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware in your
> application's global middleware stack. These middleware are listed in
> the global middleware stack by the `App\Http\Kernel` class. These
> middleware will automatically trim all incoming string fields on the
> request, as well as convert any empty string fields to `null`. This
> allows you to not have to worry about these normalization concerns in
> your routes and controllers.